# Jinja2, no module on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, jinja2

When I installed Ubuntu 16.04 my script work without 
      pip install jinja2
But,when I try to make it in docker, it write: 
     No module jinja2
I installed it, installed all dependencies..but doesn't work..

What's problem it  may be?

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: There is: " no module jinja2"

Comment: What do you try to do, what do you expect to happen and what actually happens. Those need to be explained in detail in order for anyone to help you with your problem.